# How do I visualize acceleration?

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to create a visualization for IMU sensor (acceleration in my case). I wanted to create a plug-in or some visualization that allows to see the acceleration as a time plot for each axis, displayed in a separate windows, as the camera display.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9381/how-do-i-visualize-acceleration?/) by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 408 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to create a visualization for IMU sensor (acceleration in my case). I wanted to create a plug-in or some visualization that allows to see the acceleration as a time plot for each axis, displayed in a separate windows, as the camera display.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

---

Originally posted by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) with karma: 408 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2011-03-18**:
Didn't know this application, this works for the time being.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-03-18**:
The easiest option is using `rxplot` to display the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before writing a plugin, try some of the built-in Marker options, such as [view-oriented text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#View-Oriented_Text_.28TEXT_VIEW_FACING.3D9.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2011-03-13**:
I've already used that, but now I need to display a new type of data, and it would be really nice if I could create a custom way to display it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As joq says: Use rxplot.
Using kinect_aux to send out the kinect imu data on /imu you can plot the values by:

```
rxplot /imu/linear_acceleration/x /imu/linear_acceleration/y /imu/linear_acceleration/z
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1